# How to display the CSS gradient generated by Illustrator?

Tags: html, css, gradient, adobe-illustrator

As a designer I can extract this CSS code from Illustrator:

```
.test
    {
      background : -moz-linear-gradient(0% 50% 0deg,rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%,rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%,rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%,rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%,rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%,rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%,rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      background : -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%, rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%, rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%, rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%, rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%, rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      background : -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 50% ,100% 50% ,color-stop(0,rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) ),color-stop(0.0839,rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) ),color-stop(0.287,rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) ),color-stop(0.485,rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) ),color-stop(0.6739,rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) ),color-stop(0.8498,rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) ),color-stop(1,rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) ));
      background : -o-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%, rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%, rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%, rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%, rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%, rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      background : -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%, rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%, rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%, rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%, rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%, rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2996CC', endColorstr='#430D66' ,GradientType=0)";
      background : linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%, rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%, rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%, rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%, rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%, rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      position : absolute ;
      left : 215px;
      top : 151px;
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2996CC',endColorstr='#430D66' , GradientType=1);
    }
```

I tried in the browser like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* css code here */
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="test" id="test"> </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

What am i missing?

It is a gradient rectangle, is should look like this:

[image]

Comment: for the next time you post a question, please explain your result or provide a js fiddle. In this case the solution was quite simple, you need to add a height and width to the div so there is something to display, but it could be hard to know what to solve if we dont know in what way it fails :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the width and height of the element with the gradient applied to it in the CSS:

```css
.test {
      background : -moz-linear-gradient(0% 50% 0deg,rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%,rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%,rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%,rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%,rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%,rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%,rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      background : -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%, rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%, rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%, rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%, rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%, rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      background : -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 50% ,100% 50% ,color-stop(0,rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) ),color-stop(0.0839,rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) ),color-stop(0.287,rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) ),color-stop(0.485,rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) ),color-stop(0.6739,rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) ),color-stop(0.8498,rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) ),color-stop(1,rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) ));
      background : -o-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%, rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%, rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%, rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%, rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%, rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      background : -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%, rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%, rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%, rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%, rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%, rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2996CC', endColorstr='#430D66' ,GradientType=0)";
      background : linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%, rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%, rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%, rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%, rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%, rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      position : absolute ;
      left : 100px;
      top : 50px;
      width:300px;
      height: 150px;
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2996CC',endColorstr='#430D66' , GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have forgot to set `width` and `height`.. check updated snippet below..

```css
.test
    {
      background : -moz-linear-gradient(0% 50% 0deg,rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%,rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%,rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%,rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%,rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%,rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%,rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      background : -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%, rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%, rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%, rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%, rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%, rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      background : -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 50% ,100% 50% ,color-stop(0,rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) ),color-stop(0.0839,rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) ),color-stop(0.287,rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) ),color-stop(0.485,rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) ),color-stop(0.6739,rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) ),color-stop(0.8498,rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) ),color-stop(1,rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) ));
      background : -o-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%, rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%, rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%, rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%, rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%, rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      background : -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%, rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%, rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%, rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%, rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%, rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2996CC', endColorstr='#430D66' ,GradientType=0)";
      background : linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(41, 150, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(45, 130, 189, 1) 8.39%, rgba(53, 89, 158, 1) 28.7%, rgba(59, 56, 134, 1) 48.5%, rgba(63, 32, 116, 1) 67.39%, rgba(66, 18, 106, 1) 84.98%, rgba(67, 13, 102, 1) 100%);
     /* position : absolute ;
      left : 215px;
      top : 151px;*/
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2996CC',endColorstr='#430D66' , GradientType=1);
      
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```